# Metaprogramming or other better way to handle virtual view fields in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

In my application I have a large amount of virtual fields. Virtual fields is what I call input fields on the view that drive some behaviour in the controller, but are not stored in the database.

The solution I have implemented works, but is inflexible and has a lot of overhead. I wonder if there is a better way.

In my view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.input :present_indicatif, :as => :boolean, label: "Présent de l'indicatif", :input_html => { checked: false } %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.input :imparfait_indicatif, :as => :boolean, label: "Imparfait de l'indicatif", :input_html => { checked: false } %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.input :passe_simple_indicatif, :as => :boolean, label: "Passé simple", :input_html => { checked: false } %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.input :futur_anterieur_indicatif, :as => :boolean, label: "Futur", :input_html => { checked: false } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and many more fields.

Then I seperate the virtual fields from the actual database fields in the controller

```
    def deck_params
      params.require(:deck).permit(:deck, :fluent_language,  :target_language, :status, :user_id, :deck_type, :all_verbs,
                              :present_indicatif, :imparfait_indicatif, :passe_simple_indicatif ... etc ...]
                              )
    end

    def deck_only_params
      deck_params.select { |k,v| [:deck, :fluent_language, :target_language, :status, :user_id, :deck_type].include?(k.to_sym) }
    end

    def virtual_params
      vp = params.require(:deck).select { |k,v| [
    :present_indicatif, :imparfait_indicatif, :passe_simple_indicatif, :futur_anterieur_indicatif,
    :passe_anterieur, ... etc ...
      ].include?(k.to_sym) }
      res = vp.reject { |k,v| v == "0" }
      res
    end
```

Ideally I'd like to store the list of virtual fields in an array or hash, and iterate through them to produce the view fields in erb, and also keep them quite separated from the actual fields in a clean way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me that each of the virtual fields will have a custom label.  Why not create an array of names and labels:

```
@virtual_fields = [{field:'field_1',label:'Field Number One'},{field:'field_2',label:'Field Number Two'},{field:'field_3',label:'Field Number Three'}]
```

In your view

```
<%virtual_fields.each do |vf|%>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= f.input @model_with_vf.send(vf[:field]), :as => :boolean, label: vf[:label], :input_html => { checked: false } %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

This could of course be abstracted further to move the actual labels for the fields into the model, and have a function that takes the field name in and retrieves the label.